# Прозрачная панель в WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Как можно задать прозрачность panel1 в WinForms? Кроме этого варианта ничего не работает в VS2015.

```
public sealed class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)), this.ClientRectangle);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Самому нарисовать в OnPaint перебрав Parent.Controls?

Comment: _"Как можно задать прозрачность"_ -- см. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359642/5673266, а если нужна для формы/окна, то см. WS_EX_LAYERED

Answer (score 4):

Так можно сделать панель, да и любой другой контрол, прозрачным в любой момент времени, без переписывания `OnPaint()`. Ну не совсем прозрачным. просто из всей панели, для отрисовки остаются только контролы размещенные на ней. Неприкрытые контролами части панели просто не обрабатываются.

```
GraphicsPath gr = new GraphicsPath();
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    gr.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(c.Location, c.Size));
}
panel1.Region = new Region(gr);
```

С помощью свойства `Region` и объектов `GraphicsPath` можно придать контролу WinForms любую, сколь угодно сложную форму, например криволинейный многоугольник с дырками или N независимых фрагментов работающих как один контрол.

**Upd**

Такой вариант:

```
panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

не работает, точнее работает не так как ожидается. Контрол копирует цвет фона родительского контрола, на этом "прозрачность" и заканчивается. т.е. если у вас под такой панелью окажется другой контрол, то виден он не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вот такой способ:

```
panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0);
panel1.Parent = this;
```

Вместо this нужно подставить контрол над которым располагается ваша панель.
Но она будет прозрачна только по отношению к этому контролу.
С помощью первого параметра метода FromArgb() можно контролировать степень прозрачности.

Answer (score 0):

У панели задайте любой цвет. К примеру черный
после чего нужно просто прописать у формы TransparencyKey и выбрать цвет который хотите сделать прозрачным:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.BackColor = Color.Black; 
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Black;
        }
```