# Как сделать форму прозрачной, а контролы неизменными?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать форму прозрачной, а контролы оставить без изменения?
При `TransparencyKey = BackColor` получается вот как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: c# наследует с++, по идее это означает что нужно создать "дырявый" регион *createregion* и назначить его окну http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308667/how-do-i-make-a-genuinely-transparent-control

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487760/198316 возможно подойдет, просто сделайте тоже самое для формы, вместо панели

Comment: а контролы без изменения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`TransparencyKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Задайте этому свойству такой же цвет, как у фона формы. Как результат, фон формы станет прозрачным.

```
TransparencyKey = BackColor;
```

Учтите, что **этот** цвет станет прозрачным **на всех** контролах формы. Поэтому, вероятно, придётся либо свойству `BackColor` назначить какой-нибудь экзотичный малоиспользуемый цвет, либо **у каждого** контрола **индивидуально** его менять.

Comment: Спасибо, но качество не очень. Что-то можно сделать? И форма получилась как бы дырявой )) Не эффект прозрачности, а при отсутствии контрола в форме просто дыра

Comment: @АлександрПузанов - Что значит "не очень"? Форма становится прозрачной - что и требовалось. Какие там дыры - не понимаю. Приложи скриншот.